# GRPC C++ Non-blocking server

Tags: c++, server, grpc, nonblocking

I am relatively new to GRPC and I am trying to create a grpc server from within an MFC Application. However, the `server->Wait()` statement is blocking and thus holds up the entire application.

Is there a way to make it non-blocking? Or to Shutdown the server after it has served a single RPC request instead of waiting indefinitely?

Example of the code:

```
void RunServer() {
        std::string server_address("127.0.0.1:50055");
        TestReceiverImpl service("Output.txt");

        ServerBuilder builder;
        builder.RegisterService(&service);
        builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());

        server = builder.BuildAndStart();
        std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

        //server->Wait(); <<-- Blocking code
    }
```

Comment: See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc for an example async server without the blocking call to `server->Wait()`. If you want to stick with the simpler synchronous blocking approach, you're service implementation could call the `Shutdown` method [doc](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_server_interface.html#a644772d11101318f1424e595dee73ccf) after handling an RPC.

Comment: Hi,have you found a workable solution ?

Comment: Hi Max, Unfortunately no. One approach is to use multi-threading i.e., starting the GRPC server from a different thread. Since I moved the GRPC development to C# now, I cannot test multi-threading in C++. But, it should work. All the best!